# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory using Cygwin

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an android app using cordova, and I need the sdkmanager to set the permission. Also, I had to install Cygwin because it was need to use SDKman.

This is what I get in the terminal:

```
user@DESKTOP ~
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/user/jdk

user@DESKTOP ~
$ java --version
openjdk 19.0.1 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)

user@DESKTOP ~
$ sdkmanager.bat

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /home/user/jdk

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

user@DESKTOP ~
$ whereis sdkmanager.bat
sdkmanager: /home/user/android_sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager.bat
```

Java itself seems to be working fine, but whenever I try to run the sdkmanager it doesn't find it.

Here is my .bashrc

```bash
#ANDROID SDK PATH
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android_sdk"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$ANDROID_HOME"
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/jdk"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

And my file structure

```
android_sdk:
  - build-tools
  - cmdline-tools
  - platform-tools
  - tools

jdk:
  - bin
  - conf
  - include
  - ...
```

Comment: you run `sdkmanager.bat`. bat files are usualy windows scripts so it probably expects to find windows-formatted paths. Is there a `sdkmanager.sh`?

Comment: The very fact that sdkmanager.bat exists at all should give you a different perspective on *Also, I had to install Cygwin because it was need to use SDKman.* perhaps?

Comment: @jhamon, I don't have a bash script available. However, by modifying the file I could make it work by manually writing the path into the code. It's not an appropriate solution, but thanks for your comment, it helped a lot. Another important thing is that it was unnecessary to format it as a windows-like path, it worked correctly anyway.

Comment: Have you tryed to run sdkmanager.bat from windows instead of cygwin ?